# Add '/' character in between a number (which should be formatted as a date) and turn it to a date

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates, date

I have received a spreadsheet which has the dates formatted with only numbers without separators and I would like to transform them into a date format. For example, I would like to change the number 20201130 to 2020/11/30. How could I do it?

[image: example]

Comment: **Please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you**. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",, 
        REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A2:A,"#"),"(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})","$1/$2/$3")^1))
```

*(adjust the range to your needs and format as date)*

[image]

**How the formula works:**
Because `REGEXREPLACE` takes only text values we use `TEXT` to turn the numbers to text, edit them and then turn them again to numbers using `^1`.
We also use the `IF` function to get rid of blank cells and `ArrayFormula` to do the whole column in one go.

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)